# Safe alternative to partial records?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to figure out a reasonable way to let users of my library supply me with a bunch of functions to control the way it behaves.  I'd like to supply them with some defaults they can combine and override as they see fit.  The obvious way (to me) is just a record of functions like `Foo {a, b, c, d, e}` and make it a monoid and then provide some default values they can `mappend` together.  But the defaults I make wouldn't provide all the functions.  So I might have a record with `{a, b}` and one with `{c, d}` and another with `{b, c, e}`.  That obviously isn't safe, and a user could supply me with a record like `{a, b, c, e}` which would be bad.  I want the user to be able to mix and match pieces like that, but still have to end up with a complete record.

Is there a safe way to do something like this?  If I made all the functions in the record into Maybe functions then I am at least making it so I can check if the supplied value is missing a function, but then they are still getting that error at runtime instead of compile time.  I would much rather have the "all fields in the record must be provided" invariant enforced by the compiler if I can.

Comment: If you truly need partial defaults I don't think there is a tidy solution. If you want compile-time safety you need to bring the distinction into type level, through either (in increasing order of messiness) Foo-building functions with different combinations of arguments, a corresponding `PreFoo` sum type with one constructor per partial default or multiple separate pre-Foo types serving the same purpose.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [data-default](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default) package. Using this, you can safely initialize the default values for your types. Example:

```
import Data.Default

data Foo = Foo { a :: Int, b :: Int }

instance Default Foo where
  def = Foo 3 3
```

Now using `def` you can use the default value in any function you need:

```
dummyFun :: Foo -> Foo
dummyFun x = def
```

You can also change the record value as required by you:

```
dummyFun :: Foo -> Foo
dummyFun x = def { b = 8 }
```

Comment: There is no singular default I can fill in for them.  That is why they need to supply all the functions.

Comment: @user3261399 Would it make sense to provide arbitrary defaults? Also, I might be taking your example too literally, but if you can provide, in different cases, `{a, b}`, `{c, d}` and `{a, b, c, e}` as partial defaults then it seems you have a plausible default for each field.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea about `Monoid` is a good start, but `Monoid` isn't quite general enough. What you really need is a `Category`. You could make a custom one for the job, but you can avoid even thinking about categories by just giving up on the idea of having a single fixed type to represent a partial record and instead let partial records with different fields present have different types. This means you're working with the category of types and functions, sometimes called **Hask**, but you don't have to think about that. Caveat: one of the fancy record packages on Hackage probably makes this sort of thing much easier to do, but I don't (yet) understand any of them sufficiently well to use them, let alone recommend them.

First the boiler-plate

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module PartialRec where
import Data.Proxy
```

Now the types. `PList` represents a (partial) record. Its first argument list represents the types of the record field, while the second argument list indicates which fields are present.

```
-- Skip is totally unnecessary, but makes the
-- syntax of skips a bit less horrible.
data Skip = Skip
infixr 6 `PCons`, `PSkip`
data PList :: [*] -> [Bool] -> * where
  PNil :: PList '[] '[]
  PCons :: a -> PList as bs -> PList (a ': as) ('True ': bs)
  PSkip :: Skip -> PList as bs -> PList (a ': as) ('False ': bs)
```

We use a type family to express how the *types* combine when two partial records are combined. In particular, any field present in either partial record will be present in the result.

```
type family Combine (as :: [Bool]) (bs :: [Bool]) :: [Bool] where
  Combine '[] '[] = '[]
  Combine ('True ': xs) (y ': ys) = 'True ': Combine xs ys
  Combine ('False ': xs) (y ': ys) = y ': Combine xs ys
```

The `combine` function combines two partial records to form a new one with the same field types and any fields present in either partial record. If a field is present in both records, the first one is chosen.

```
combine :: PList as bs -> PList as cs -> PList as (Combine bs cs)
combine PNil PNil = PNil
combine (PCons x xs) (PSkip _ ys) = PCons x (combine xs ys)
combine (PSkip _ xs) (PCons y ys) = PCons y (combine xs ys)
combine (PSkip _ xs) (PSkip _ ys) = PSkip Skip (combine xs ys)
combine (PCons x xs) (PCons _ ys) = PCons x (combine xs ys)
```

The defaulting logic is left to `buildRec`. `buildRec` takes a partial record with a sufficient set of fields, and produces values for the optional fields based on the required fields and any optional fields actually present. `buildRec` is actually implemented using a type class with instances chosen by a type family, in order to support multiple sufficient field sets.

```
-- Names for instances
data BuilderTag = Builder1 | Builder2

-- Given a list of types present, determines
-- the correct Builder instance to use.
type family ChooseBuilder (present :: [Bool]) :: BuilderTag where
  ChooseBuilder '[ 'True, 'True, 'True, b3 ] = Builder2
  ChooseBuilder '[ 'True, b1, 'True, b2 ] = Builder1

class Builder (tag :: BuilderTag) (present :: [Bool]) where
  buildRec' :: proxy tag -> PList '[Int, Char, Bool, Integer] present -> (Int, Char, Bool, Integer)

buildRec :: forall tag present . (Builder tag present, tag ~ ChooseBuilder present)
         => PList '[Int, Char, Bool, Integer] present -> (Int, Char, Bool, Integer)
buildRec xs = buildRec' (Proxy :: Proxy tag) xs

instance Builder 'Builder1 '[ 'True, b1, 'True, b2 ] where
  buildRec' _ (i `PCons` Skip `PSkip` b `PCons` Skip `PSkip` PNil) = (i, toEnum (i + fromEnum b) , b, if i > 3 && b then 12 else 13)
  buildRec' _ (i `PCons` Skip `PSkip` b `PCons` intg `PCons` PNil) = (i, toEnum (i + fromEnum b + fromIntegral intg), b, intg)
  buildRec' _ (i `PCons` c `PCons` b `PCons` Skip `PSkip` PNil) = (i, c, b, fromIntegral i)
  buildRec' _ (i `PCons` c `PCons` b `PCons` intg `PCons` PNil) = (i, c, b, intg)

instance Builder 'Builder2 '[ 'True, 'True, 'True, b3 ] where
  buildRec' _ (i `PCons` c `PCons` b `PCons` Skip `PSkip` PNil) = (i, c, b, fromIntegral i)
  buildRec' _ (i `PCons` c `PCons` b `PCons` intg `PCons` PNil) = (i, c, b, intg)
```

Here are some functions to build partial records with a single field each.

```
justInt :: Int -> PList '[Int, a, b, c] '[ 'True, 'False, 'False, 'False]
justInt x = x `PCons` Skip `PSkip` Skip `PSkip` Skip `PSkip` PNil

justChar :: Char -> PList '[a, Char, b, c] '[ 'False, 'True, 'False, 'False]
justChar x = Skip `PSkip` x `PCons` Skip `PSkip` Skip `PSkip` PNil

justBool :: Bool -> PList '[a, b, Bool, c] '[ 'False, 'False, 'True, 'False]
justBool x = Skip `PSkip` Skip `PSkip` x `PCons` Skip `PSkip` PNil

justInteger :: Integer -> PList '[a, b, c, Integer] '[ 'False, 'False, 'False, 'True]
justInteger x = Skip `PSkip` Skip `PSkip` Skip `PSkip` x `PCons` PNil
```

Here are some sample uses. `useChar` will end up using the `Builder2` instance, while `noChar` will use the `Builder1` instance.

```
useChar :: (Int, Char, Bool, Integer)
useChar = buildRec $ justInt 12 `combine` justBool False `combine` justChar 'c'

noChar :: (Int, Char, Bool, Integer)
noChar = buildRec $ justInt 12 `combine` justBool False
```

Comment: Your "combine" is called "record override" in [Bracha and Lindstrom](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.34.8782) Have you found in the meantime if there are less horrible ways to do this in Haskell? I see there's a blog/wiki page... https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/records

Comment: @Fizz, it's been almost four years since I wrote this, and I don't think I've thought about it since. There may well be better approaches! Right now my Haskell playtime is focused on `<*` for `Data.Sequence`; I really want to put that to bed....

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `data` type with exactly the option combinations you want. And don't be shy sacrificing commutativity of your settings monoid. In the end it would be like the CLI programs with subcommands (like git, hg, dnf etc) whose option syntax differ.